# XNA Strange blur on my transparency .png

Tags: xna, blur, gimp

(i can't post images so i posted links instead)

i'm working on a 2D platform game using pixelperfect.

The problem is about the png images used in-game. On transparency, there are some blur.

like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBX3A.jpg

If i open the texture with TheGimp, this is what i get :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOeF4.jpg

this is a sample of my map (zoom 1600x).

As you can see there is no blur around the black. (the grey squares means transparency).

Tests i did :

- save without compression and re-opened it = no blur.
- to be sure, i added a white background in gimp (it's easier to see the dark blur on white) :

(http://) i.stack.imgur.com/jfhWv.jpg

of course, i removed the white background because i wanted it transparency.

last information : there is blur on every transparency png images, even on my spritesheet character. When i animate it, i can see the blur from others frames.

After my tests, i concluded that gimp isn't the problem.
Can you help me ? Thx for reading.

xna4, c#2010 express edition, gimp2.611.
Sorry about my english ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of "texture filtering", which xna does by default.
You probaly can disable this.

found something: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0

Comment: Yes i know, don't worry ^^. i couldn't because of a cooldown :(.